# Overwrite ls in .bash_profile

Tags: bash, ls, .bash-profile, alias

I'm new to bash and unix. I'm trying to create an alias for ls. In my .bash_profile I have the following:

```
alias ls="ls -lhHG"
```

This doesn't work at all. If I change it to:

```
alias la="ls -lhHG"
```

then everything but G (showing pretty colors) works.

Right now my $Path is

```
/opt/local/bin:/Users/clang/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

The only other stuff in my .bash_profile is

```
1 export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim
2 export PATH=/opt/local/bin:~/bin:$PATH
```

Again, I'm totally new to this so please go easy on me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'doesn't work'. what are you seeing, and what do you want to happen.  Also, what platform?  Linux, OSX? It is significant what flags to pass to `ls` to 'work'

Comment: By doesn't work I mean when I try to run the command ls it just runs the ls command with no additional options. The platform is OSX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you edit `.bash_profile`, make sure you source it into your current environment with:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Or:

```
. .bash_profile
```

Then, your new modified commands should be available to you.

Comment: Thanks! I'm away from my mac atm but when I get in tomorrow I'll try this first thing

Comment: That did it. Thanks so much. Now I'm off to learn vim... I have a feeling I'll be back soon

Comment: @clang : That's why we're here ;)